# TortoiseHg error unknown revision '72323098234082394....'

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

We use `TortoiseHg` to work with our repositories. On several PCs they receive the following error when attempting to do a merge from the TortoiseHg GUI (clicking the toolbar button):

[image: example error from TortoiseHg]

Clicking the refresh button as directed doesn't have any effect on this problem.

However, going to the Tortoise console and manually commanding `hg merge` works fine. No errors that way. So this seems to be a Tortoise-specific issue.

Note that the huge number `73707418...` might actually be a list of 4-digit revision numbers. Our revisions are up around 7400 right now.

Does anyone know the cause of this problem and ideally a fix?

---

Note - there is not a message like

> abort: unknown revision 'xxxx'

which is mainly what I find Googling this problem. Those issues seem to be unrelated.

Comment: kudos to tortoise for implementing 256(?)bit ID values... now that's thinking ahead to the Y999999999999999999k problem....

Comment: @Marc B actually thanks for mentioning that - that crazy number may actually be a list of revision numbers...